# Identify All Points in a Circle Sector

Tags: geometry, circles

We need to identify all points in a circle sector, which is marked in yellow color in the image below. We know 4 points: $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ and $P_4$. Assume that point coordinates are integer numbers. Can you help to identify the points optimally?

[image]

Comment: Please explain more: (1) What do you mean by *points*? Do you mean all points that make up the yellow area, or do you mean points with integer coordinates that are located in the yellow area? (2) What do you mean by identifying the points *optimally*? Is this an optimization problem? (3) What do you mean by *identifying* the points in the yellow area? Do you mean you want to geometrically construct that area? (5) Are the radii of the circles or the coordinates of the center known?